# Generic way to handle all AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there a way to detect all AJAX calls (both GET and POST)? I need to do a generic way to show a loading div while the AJAX call process are running. Something like the code below:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'my/url',
   type: "GET",
   dataType: "json",
   beforeSend: function() {
       $('#loading').show();
   },
   success: function() {
       $('#loading').hide();
       // do some stuff...
}
```

Instead to call in every AJAX `beforeSend()` and `success()` behaviors (show and hide the loading div), I'm searching a generic way to handle it. When I have an AJAX call, I just do it:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'my/url',
   type: "GET",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function() {
       // do some stuff...
}
```

When that `beforeSend()` behavior is implicity in this request and the same for the `success()` hide behavior. Do you have any idea how can I treat this thing?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using [`.ajaxStart()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) & [`.ajaxStop()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) methods like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        $('#loading').show();
    }).ajaxStop(function () {
        $('#loading').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Funnily enough, I was trying to do this myself this morning!

```
$('#loading').bind('ajaxSend', function() {
    $(this).show();
}).bind('ajaxStop', function() {
    $(this).hide();
}).bind('ajaxError', function() {
    $this.hide();
});
```

Obviously, lots of different ways to achieve this, but I prefer to bind the visibility of the loading message to the AJAX events, rather than the other way around...

Comment: Thanks, @Richard A. Your solution is pretty nice, also. I chose Palash's solution because is more easier to everyone understand. But thank you!